# Dynamic programming: matrix chain multiplication

Tags: algorithm

I am reading Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen etc on dynamic programming.

Here is text snippet which gives some back ground

> the problem of matrix-chain multiplication exhibits optimal
>   substructure. We observed that an optimal parenthesization of A1 A2 ... An that splits the product between Ak and Ak + 1 contains within it optimal solutions to the problems of parenthesizing A1 A2 ... A k and  Ak + 1 Ak + 2 . . . An.

In the book for Matrix-chain multiplication there are theta(n square) subproblems.

My question is how does author came up with there are n square sub problems?
Can any one pls give example how we came with this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is too hard to answer without immediate access to the Cormen book. You should try to flesh things a little bit more and make the question self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

Each subproblem involves solving the problem for a consecutive subsequence of matrices `Ai, Ai+1, ..., Aj-1, Aj`. This subsequence is characterized by the two indices `i` and `j`. Since there are `n` possible choices for each, the number of subproblems is theta(n<sup>2</sup>). The exact number is `n(n+1)/2` due to the constraint `i <= j`.